# PHP Paths on file_get_contents()

Tags: php

I need to use `file_get_contents()` to get the content of a html page (content.html) in a file (file.php) that is in a directory like this:

```
/content
- content.html
/functions
- file.php
```

So I tried to use `file_get_contents('../content/content.html')` to get the html content, but i get this error:

```
failed to open stream: No such file or directory
```

I think I might be using the path wrong. What can I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']** all the time, so you won't have to deal problematically with the file paths.

**Try:**

```
file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/content/content.html');
```

Comment: You were pointing to the wrong path. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] gives you the full path to apache's root. You just add folder from there.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use `__DIR__` here instead on relying on a variable set by the web server :

```
file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../content/content.html')
```

`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is error prone as it relies on the webserver (Apache in this case), if you use Nginx instead your code may break as you have to configure it to set this variable...., instead I prefer relying on `__DIR__` which is provided by PHP thus **environment agnostic**.

Comment: __DIR__ doesn't return server root folder. It returns the current folder location its file is at. Then it becomes problematic there with ../../ path components.